# Storing Controls in a variable

Tags: c#, class, controls

I want store generic controls in variable without knowing its type. By I need access to some of common properties such as name, size, location... i want to only store radio buttons, labels,picture box... can anyone give me any idea how to do this?

Comment: Figured it out set a property of Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Winforms, they all derive from Control, so just make a list of Controls like this:

```
public List<Control> MyControls;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can using `List<Control> myControls = new List<Control>();`
while Control is baseclass of each WinForm Control you can access Properties like Name .

```
myControls.add(pictureBox1);
myControls.add(textBox1);
```

Than you can also backward the Cast to Control by doing

```
if(myControls[0] is TextBox)
    TextBox txtbx1 = (TextBox)(myControls[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Controls inherit from the [base class `Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx), and it has all the properties you mention. You could type your collection of controls to contain `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as a list of the type that all those controls inherit from, which i believe would be `Control`. You can then access all the members (including properties) that are declared by the `Control` class.

```
var MyControls = new List<Control>();
MyControls.Add(MyPicBox);
MyControls.Add(MyRadioButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
List<Control> myControls = new List<Control>();
myControls.Add(new Label());
myControls.Add(new Button());
myControls.Add(new PictureBox());

foreach (var myControl in myControls)
{
     myControl.Name = "New Name";
     myControl.Size = new Size(100, 200);
     myControl.Location = new Point(100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable of Base class type. As base class type variable can hold instances of child classes.

For example in WPF you can do `List<System.Windows.Controls.Control>`

for Win Forms you can do `List<System.Windows.Forms.Control>`